# Are the Mandrakes sentient?

Tags: harry-potter, potions

In the Harry Potter books, are we to assume the Mandrakes are sentient?  They are portrayed as behaving much like human beings, such as going through adolescence, et cetera.  However, if this is the case, chopping them up for potions seems more than a little harsh.

Comment: Are the pieces of Wizard Chess sentient?

Comment: "Nah, they don't feel pain in the way we do, or at least that's what we tell ourselves, because if it weren't true, we would be monsters."

Answer (score 27):

**Yes, Mandrakes are sentient in their own way.**

First, Mandrakes are described as "babies" in *Chamber of Secrets* -- Harry is surprised when Professor Sprout pulls the first Mandrake out of its pot and it looks humanesque. The Mandrake also apparently has a gender.

> Harry let out a gasp of surprise that no one could hear.
>   Instead of roots, a small, muddy and extremely ugly baby popped out of the earth. The leaves were growing right out of his head. He had pale green, mottled skin, and was clearly bawling at the top of his lungs.
>   <sub>*Chamber of Secrets* - pages 72-73 - Bloomsbury - chapter six, *Gilderoy Lockhart*</sub>

The Mandrakes dislike being repotted and attempt to avoid being put into a new pot. This demonstrates they possess preferences.

Professor Sprout has to fit the Mandrakes with scarves in the winter which goes back to preference -- they are not immune to temperature preferences. They prefer being warm.

> The sun had now begun to shine weakly on Hogwarts again. Inside the castle, the mood had grown more hopeful. There had been no more attacks since those on Justin and Nearly Headless
>   Nick, and Madam Pomfrey was pleased to report that **the Mandrakes were becoming moody** and secretive, meaning that they were fast leaving childhood.
>   <sub>*Chamber of Secrets* - page 175 - Bloomsbury - chapter thirteen, *The Very Secret Diary*</sub>

"Moody" is a state of mind. A being cannot be moody without having a state of mind, i.e. sentience.

In March of Harry's second year, the Mandrakes throw a party in Greenhouse Three. This implies social interaction and a desire to have a shared experience with peers.

Many objects, creatures, and plants show sentience in Potterverse, where they would not in the Muggle world.

Comment: I don't think any of this proof of actual sentience... just general indications of having some sort of brain. Note we often say "X plant prefers acidic soil" without meaning the plant is sentient. Also the scarves could simply be there to keep them alive/healthy--no evidence of preference, just biology. Also, people often anthropomorphize things like these--"My tomatoes were unhappy in their new pot".

Comment: I upvoted this because it does a good job answering my question as I asked it.  However, I'm really more interested in the in-world ethics of slaughtering the Mandrakes for spells --I probably should have made that more clear.

Comment: @Valek Well, they _did_ throw a party in greenhouse three.

Comment: *Sentience* is the ability to feel, perceive, or to experience subjectivity (from Wikipedia). In sci-fi it's often used to mean self-awareness (humans being the only sentient species on earth, looking for "other sentient species", etc.) Most of the above could be applied to a dog or cat, which have personalities but not sentience. (The exception would be the throwing a party part.) The scarves part is the least convincing of all as it might be that they would die of cold without them - it doesn't necessarily indicate a *preference*.

Comment: Also: the bit on gender isn't useful. Real-world gametophyte-stage plants can be male or female (or both).

Comment: @ChrisSunami -- Yes, I did answer the question as it was asked. Your clarification in the comments mentions ethics, as in Is it ethical to slaughter Mandrakes to make potions and draughts and the like -- am I correct in how I read that? If so, why wouldn't it be ethical ... unless they *were* sentient? :)

Comment: @BrianS -- Thank you for choosing to extrapolate on plant gender to bolster your point that commenting on plant gender is actually useless. ;) ;) ;)

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart - I get what you're saying, I do. And you make great points. As to anthromorphization, Potterverse is *so much* about anthropomorphizing things -- when I wrote my answer, I tried to write it from a Potterverse POV, not that of the real world where, obviously, plants don't throw parties. Your points (and similar sentiments) are well taken, but are also why I purposefully worded my answer "Yes, Mandrakes are sentient, **in their own way**." :)

Comment: @Slytherincess It's pretty obvious that the community thinks you're right, and my Harry Potter nerd-dom is spotty at best, so I'll accept that this is probably the right answer from within mindset of the Harry Potter universe. I'll keep my previous comment though in case anyone cares to read the skeptic point of view.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart -- I really don't know if my answer *is* right. It's just my interpretation of the text. It looks to me as if way more people agree with you and feel that I *did not* answer the question well. Just because I really, really like Harry Potter doesn't mean I know everything about it or am always right. In fact, I've had to go back and majorly correct some of my answers. I've misinterpreted questions. I make mistakes, as everyone sometimes does. Maybe this is one of those times. It's totally fine to leave your skeptical comment up. :)

Comment: I still think it's a matter of sapience and not sentience..

Answer (score 11):

I think the question you are trying to ask is really if they are Sapient...

Many animals and plants are sentient but not sapient.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentience

> Sentience is the ability to feel, perceive, or to experience
>   subjectivity.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapience#Sapience

> Sapience is often defined as wisdom, or the ability of an organism or
>   entity to act with appropriate judgement, a mental faculty which is a
>   component of intelligence or alternatively may be considered an
>   additional faculty, apart from intelligence, with its own properties.

As the previous person shows proof that they have forms of sentience, but I think you were trying to compare them to humans which would mean that you are wondering if they are human like aka Sapient, which they are not.

Just to clarify there is no proof in the books that the Mandrakes show forms of wisdom or judgement.  This means that they are sentient but not sapient.  If they were able to perform complex thought processes then yes they would be sapient but as I stated they do not show this in the book.

I also wanted to point out that Science Fiction in general tends to blur the lines between sentience / sapience.  As the wiki states :

> The words "sapience", "self-awareness", and "consciousness" are used
>   in similar ways in science fiction

Comment: _Sentient_ is often used in Sci-Fi to distinguish between "animals" and "people" though. I've never seen a definition outside the genre that supports this but the David Brin's Uplift saga is a good example of the word used in the sense that the OP implies. Anyway, how do you conclude they're not sapient? I can't decide from the information in the books.

Comment: Sapience would mean that they have some form of wisdom or higher form of intelligence than other species of plants / monster races in Harry Potter.

Comment: Many of the "monster races" clearly have near-human or higher intelligence (giants, merpeople, gobblins etc) but yes, I understand what sapience would mean. What I don't know is how you conclude that mandrakes don't possess it. Your answer basically consists of a discussion of what _sapience_ and _sentience_ mean, the only part of your answer that actually attempts to answer the OP is the bold statement of: _which they are not_. You offer no arguments and no evidence to support that claim so, how do you conclude that is true?

Comment: Because the mandrakes in the book only react to stuff like not trying to be planted back into their pots.  Nothing in the book shows them as being any more intelligent than let's say a dog who doesn't want to go back inside the house?  I stated that yes they show sentience as the person before showed how they were "moody", but in no way is there any proof that they are sapient.  Although you can most likely argue just because there is lack a proof it doesn't disqualify as being sapient.

Comment: Agreed, but nothing in book shows them as _not_ being more intelligent either. And you don't mention _anything_ from the book in your answer, that's my main point. You just make a claim, with no argumentation, and the rest is a discussion of semantics. To decide one way or the other, you need to defend your claim somehow.

Comment: With the limited information about Mandrakes we can affirm that they are sentient but not sapient.  His question was trying to me was asking are they like humans essentially because they characterize certain aspects of sentience.  Humans are one of the only sapient species on Earth, since the book shows nothing more than them have some forms of sentience, it is easily assumable that they are not sapient.  I mean granted there is no proof they are sapient, but consequently there's no proof they are not.  Personally I lean more towards not, because being both is rare.

Comment: Rare in real life, but not so much in science fiction... Though a lot of monster races do not seem to show much sapience anyway.

Comment: All we know is that they react just like you or I would and they exhibit a range of emotions. That does not mean they are sapient but it certainly does not mean they are not. Absence of proof is not proof of absence :).

Comment: You mean react just like any animal would to something they don't enjoy?  You're comparing how they react to something like it shows them as being human, which is not the case.

Comment: No, I am not claiming anything, one way or the other. All I'm saying is that you make a claim, but do not attempt to support it in your answer in any way.

Comment: I am supporting the claim by saying they show sentience but no signs of sapience in the book.

Comment: If they do not show any signs of sapience, you can infer that they are most likely not sapient... Hell if they were sapient pretty sure the wizards wouldn't take their roots for potions, it would most likely be seen as inhumane.

Comment: 1) Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. 2) You don't actually even say they don't show signs of sapience in the books in your answer (that was in the comments) 3) Wizards are well known speciests, that's the whole point of the question, whether it is morally decent to use them, using that as evidence is circular reasoning.

Comment: Read the edit I made I clearly state there is no evidence of sapience in the books.  It's morally decent to use them because they are not considered sapient in general.