# What part of the mandrake plant is used for the restorative draught?

Tags: harry-potter, potions

Mandrake (Mandragora) is an essential component of the Mandrake Restorative Draught.

The question is, what part of the plant is used?
The leaves? The human-like root? All of it?

[image]

Would Prof.  Sprout, the person who takes care of the Whomping Willow, agree to cutting up and boiling the mandrake creatures? After all they look and [behave like humans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52611/are-the-mandrakes-sentient).  (At same point they go through puberty, described as moody and secrerive, even throwing a party in Greenhouse Three) on the other hand, mandrakes are used as projectiles in the Battle of Hogwarts.

Comment: Wasn't Sprout the one who mentioned chopping and stewing them?  Didn't seem like she had a problem with it.

Comment: @Radhil chopping and stewing which part?

Comment: She didn't mention one - which leads me to believe she meant the main body, since they wouldn't be that dangerous of a plant if they just needed to pluck a leaf off the top.

Comment: @Radhil maybe it's dangerous to handle,  like to move it to a bigger pot which needs to be done occasionally? She even demonstrated how it's done and said earmuffs are needed for the re-pot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know for certain that Mandrake *leaves* were used in a variety of potions...

> *He, Ron and Hermione sat in the library as the sun set outside,
> tearing feverishly through page after page of spells, hidden from each
> other by the massive piles of books on the desk in front of each of
> them. Harry’s heart gave a huge leap every time he saw the word
> ‘water’ on a page, but more often than not it was merely ‘Take two
> pints of water, **half a pound of shredded mandrake leaves** and a newt
> …’.*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry potter and the Goblet of Fire</sup></sub>

...and other magics...

> For the space of one entire month (from full moon to full moon), **a
> single leaf from a Mandrake must be carried constantly in the mouth**.
> The leaf must not be swallowed or taken out of the mouth at any point.
> If the leaf is removed from the mouth, the process must be started
> again.
>
> <sub><sup>[Short Stories from Hogwarts of Heroism, Hardship and Dangerous Hobbies](https://www.pottermore.com/news/pottermore-presents-ebook-series-published-september)</sup></sub>

But the only specific reference that the *root* was used in the restorative draught seems to come from the [Gameboy Color game](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zMpsLdTYxFw/hqdefault.jpg) (where you need to collect "***Mandrake Root***" in order to finish the potion and complete the level) and the [Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince video game](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Half-Blood_Prince_(video_game)) where Harry comments

> *"Stewed Mandrake. Much quieter than the live version."*

---

That all being said, the *implication* is very very clear. **It's the root that's used, not just the leaves.**

> ‘We will be able to cure her, Argus,’ said Dumbledore patiently.
> ‘Professor Sprout recently managed to procure some Mandrakes. **As soon
> as they have reached their full size, I will have a potion made which
> will revive Mrs Norris.’**
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets</sup></sub>